# stop timer if interval reach to 0

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to stop the timer if it reach to 0.I need to stop the countdown at 00.00 and display `alert(countdown stopped)`.now It starts again.need to stop after reach to 00.00

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * .05,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">start</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearInterval() function?

Comment: FYI, accurate timers are displayed by using `Date.now()` and computing elapsed time from some start time, not by decrementing a counter in `setInterval()` because `setInterval()` is not guaranteed to run on time - particularly in mobile devices where it may be suspended at times for power management reasons.

Comment: ya If I used if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        } clearInterval(timer);

Comment: You have to save the return result from `setInterval()` if you want to ever use `clearInterval()` on it.

Comment: @ jfriend00  I need to fix it in any possible ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use clearInterval as show in snippet.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var __timer = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(__timer);
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * .05,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">start</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Orr you could wrap this line of code

```
if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
```

with

```
  if (display.textContent != "0:00") {

            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
        }
```